# Android SMS to Email

Tags: android, email, sms

This is what I have so far. It works with phone numbers but when I put an email address in, nothing happens

```
  private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage("xxx@gmail.com", null, message, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How it will do? It's wrong way. it only can send SMS. for email you will need to do different code. You are using wrong code, it's only take valid mobile number.

For email:

```
sendEmail("xxx@example.com");

     public void sendEmail(String to) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String to = textTo.getText().toString().trim();
          String subject="XXX-- Android App";
          String message =" ";

          Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
          //email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
          email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

          //need this to prompts email client only
          email.setType("message/rfc822");

          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Send Email......"));
    }
```

Enjoy!!!